# jQuery Sortable not working for nested elements

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm trying to get jQuery sortable to rearrange a div nested hierarchy. My divs can have child divs, that can be ordered or dragged outside the parent so they become siblings etc.

I have an example at:
http://jsfiddle.net/xu7xN/

that basically has this layout:

```
<div id="root">
    <div class="box">
        <div class="header">box a</div>
        <div class="content">
            <div class="box">
                <div class="header">box b</div>
                <div class="content"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="box">
                <div class="header">box c</div>
                <div class="content"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
        <div class="header">box d</div>
        <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Using the connectWith option, I should be able to:

- drag "box a" below "box d" and all of "box a"s children go with it
- drag "box d" into "box a" so it becomes a child
- drag "box b" to #root so it becomes a root node

I thought this would be easy but I thought wrong, is there something obviously wrong that I'm doing?

Comment: To answer my own question, I was doing $(".box").sortable, whereas I should have used $(".content").sortable

Answer (score 1):

This blog post looks like it covers a similar issue and resolves it. It's based around lists instead of divs but the code should still apply [jQuery UI nested sortables](http://a.shinynew.me/post/4641524290/jquery-ui-nested-sortables)

Comment: This should have been a comment instead of an answer

Comment: agreed but I'm currently 7 points off being able to add comments and thought the link could solve the OP's issue